# Trigger IFTT from Windows Command Line

Tags: ifttt

I have a Tuya-based smart outlet and want to be able to trigger it on/off via windows command line.  It appears all of the Tuya API is built for Linux.  If I link my outlet to IFTTT is there a user-friendly way to control that outlet via batch file/command line?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using CURL to call the IFTTT webhook, one for an the outlet's "on" command and another for an "off" command.  I can then use these CURL calls in my batch file and trigger the outlet on/off as needed.